# How to show child component loading text in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

In my "event.component" I have a child component (app-grouplist)

```
<div class="group-list">
<app-grouplist
[hasStarted]="started"
[hasEnded]="ended"
Loading Groups... </app-grouplist>
</div>
```

On initial load of the page, the child component is not shown immediately. What I want to do is, show the "Loading Groups..." text while the child component has not yet shown.

Comment: can you show the reason about `the child component is not shown immediately`?

Comment: Because this child component loads a data from an API service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use if / else logic in templates with ngIf like:

```
<app-grouplist *ngIf="childrenReady;else loading"
    [hasStarted]="started"
    [hasEnded]="ended">
</app-grouplist>

<ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
```

For this to work, you need to set a variable that knows when the children are ready to display, called childrenReady in this example.  This will display the app-grouplist if that is true, but the content in the "#loading template if not.

You could also do this logic in the child component rather than the container if the container doesn't / can't know the status of the children.

Comment: Tinalo ako ni boss amo :(

Answer (score 1):

In your child component. You can use ng-content to display parent model. For example.

Parent Component

```
<app-grouplist [hasStarted]="started" [hasEnded]="ended">Loading Groups...</app-grouplist>
```

Child Component

```
<ng-content *ngIf="loading else loadedData"></ng-content>

<div *ngIf="loading" #loadedData>....elem here...</div>
```

Don't forget to add variable loading: boolean in your child component typescript code.